# How to exit of program on android

Tags: java, android

How to exit from my app on button click in **Android** app?
I've tried button click event method. Tell me the code or logic for it.

java file:

```
  Button button;
    button=(Button) findViewById(R.id.exit);
    button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                }
            });
```

Comment: `finish();` is all you need.

Comment: why you canceled my answer? Does not work?

Answer (score 0):

```
 @Override
        public void onClick(View paramView) 
      {
            finish();          
            moveTaskToBack(true);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Just make a `finish();` as follows :

```
Button button;
button=(Button) findViewById(R.id.exit);
button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
              finish();
            }
        });
```

What does `finish()` do?

> Call this when your activity is done and should be closed. The ActivityResult is propagated back to whoever launched you via onActivityResult().

For more information read the [`finish() documentation`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#finish())

### EDIT

Add this on your `manifest.xml` file :

```
<activity
   android:autoRemoveFromRecents="true"/>
```

If you want to avoid `finish();` just call an `Intent` like this :

```
Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_EXCLUDE_FROM_RECENTS);
i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
startActivity(i);
```

### EDIT with sample

My `manifest.xml`

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:excludeFromRecents="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

My `setOnClickListener()`

```
btn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button);

    btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent1 = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
            intent1.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_EXCLUDE_FROM_RECENTS);
            intent1.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
            startActivity(intent1);
            //finish(); it can also be done

        }
    });
```

Comment: I've edited my answer, btw what do you mean with `with this code program does not close coplitly`?

Comment: I want to close program and can not see program in recent apps.

Comment: finish() will only destroy the activity not the application.

Comment: What if this button is in Activity B and user navigated from Activity A to Activity B? Finishing Activity B will bring Activity A to foreground.

Comment: @m.asadi You should add more code, because where I'm testing it it does.

Comment: please write program and sent to me and I testing

Comment: @m.asadi Edited my quesiton

Answer (score 0):

**In Android is not recommended to close/kill applications**, because that is already done by OS automatically when needed. As [@33go](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1666116/323go) user already recommended, calling finish() in your application should be enough. **But** if you really want to stop the process in an easy way you can **try this**, from everywhere in your app:

```
System.exit(0);
```

Answer (score -1):

try

```
android.os.Process.killProcess(android.os.Process.myPid());
```

Comment: call `super.onBackPressed()`

Answer (score -1):

Just try to double back press to exit your application. Paste this code to your activity:

```
    private static long back_pressed;

    @Override
    public void onBackpressed()
    {
       if (back_pressed + 2000 > System.currentTimeMillis()) {
         super.onBackPressed();
       } else {
         Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Press once again to exit!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
       }
       this.back_pressed = System.currentTimeMillis();
    }
```

Comment: That's only a message before the app gets in background! It does not really close your application

Comment: If you are set total finish then change onBackPressed to finish(); in if statement